# migration with datamapper

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I need to add another column (email) to my User model. I do not wish to modify the existing data in MySql database. How should I do that?

Below is code of my original model class, and I am using Sinatra. Thanks in advance.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'data_mapper'

DataMapper.setup(:default,'mysql://root@localhost/database')

class User
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id,              Serial
  property :name,            String, :unique=>true, :required=>true
end

DataMapper.finalize
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple things like adding a new column, you can modify your model and then call `auto_upgrade!`, like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'data_mapper'

class User
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id,              Serial
  property :name,            String, :unique=>true, :required=>true
  property :email,           String, :unique=>true, :required=>true
end

DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper::Logger.new(STDOUT,  :debug)
DataMapper.setup(:default,'mysql://root@localhost/database')
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

Notice that I changed where `setup` is called, so that an SQL log is created before the connection is set up. Here the SQL log includes the following line:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD COLUMN `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
```

Which I believe does what you want, without altering existing data. Notice, however, that if you wanted to change the features of a column (e.g., changing the size of fields), this wouldn't work. DataMapper doesn't check for that kind of change.

Comment: I use DataMapper.auto_upgrade! too. It works out of the box all the time for me.